# How to Configure Nginx reverse proxy for 2 apps running on the same machin on different ports

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

On my aws ubuntu (18.04) machine, I have 2 applications running on 2 ports

(1) I have a .net core 3.1 angular spa with identity server 4 running on 5000 and I set it up using the steps below

The nginx is a reverse proxy only

(2) I have an angular ssr application running on port 4000.

What I want to achieve is for the reverse proxy to proxy social media bots to port 4000 while all other requests are proxied to the 5000.

Currently nginx is only proxying to the .net core app on port 5000

Answer (score 1):

You can use "location and proxy_pass" to access your desire applications which are working on different ports.

If you have all stuffs on a same vm just use **localhost** insted of ip address i wrote it down.
But if application are running on another vm use its IP address which in my configuration the destination server is : 172.16.0.100

You can edit the hosts file and use "example.com" or whatever to point your site and use in your nginx configuration file instead of IP or localhost.

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
172.16.0.100    example.com
```

and add your desire FQDN to the destination host or if you have a dns, add an AAAA record which would be available in whole local network.

I write this configuration in my nginx server and it works like a charm.
Anyway you can write and edit this configuration base on your environment.

```html
server {
{
    listen 80;
    server_name 172.16.0.100;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    location /angular {
        proxy_pass http://172.16.0.100:5000;
    }
    location /ssr {
        proxy_pass http://172.16.0.100:4000;
    }
}
```